# Excluding Resuable global components from another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, single-page-application

So I have many components which have a sidebar and navbar code written in all of them except one component. So I did the reasonable thing and made both of them(sidebar and navbar) separate components.

Now if I import them in `App.vue`, it shows in all the components including the one I don't need them in.

How do I go about it? Btw, the App.vue is my central point and where I'm loading `router-view` from

Comment: Make a Store State Value (boolean), then set in your App.vue `<navbar v-if="yourstatevalue"></navbar>`, then in the mounted of the pages you set the store value to true or false depending on if you wanna show the navbar or not

Comment: Can you elaborate on this, kinda confusing. By store, do you mean Vuex, I'm not using Vuex (yet)

Comment: Ok, if you dont wanna use vuex simply make a `v-if="$route.path !== 'yourpathwhereyoudontwantthenavbar`

Comment: great, it works. Thanks

Comment: sidenote: If I'm using Vuex, is it the same method I'll follow but maybe this time, define the logic(v-if="$route.path !== 'path'") in my state?

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @Badgy

Make a `v-if="$route.path !== 'yourpathwhereyoudontwantthenavbar`

Example:

```
// this will not display the sidebar on the register page
<Sidebar v-if="$route.path !== '/register'" />
```

Another Alternative by myself:

Define where you want these components to appear in the meta options of your route objects https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html. It's more or less just a way to attach arbitrary information which you can fetch from the current route to determine e.g. your layouting

```
const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/users',
      name: 'users',
      component: Users,
      meta: { sidebar: true, navbar: true },
    },
  },
})

// This will make the sidebar appear in the user page
<sidebar v-if="$route.meta.sidebar">
```

You can do `<sidebar v-if="!$route.meta.sidebar">` if you don't want it just in 1 component